# difference between String.prototype.trim.call(text) and text.trim()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, trim

Looking into jQuery's source:

```
// Use native String.trim function wherever possible
trim: trim && !trim.call("\uFEFF\xA0") ?
    function( text ) {
        return text == null ?
            "" :
            trim.call( text );
    } :

    // Otherwise use our own trimming functionality
    function( text ) {
        return text == null ?
            "" :
            ( text + "" ).replace( rtrim, "" );
    },
```

is there a reason Why they use trim.call(text) instead of text.trim()? Thanks a lot!!

**UPDATE:**

Right this way it won't throw exceptions if the argument is not a string. But according to jQuery's doc, the argument is supposed to be a string so if user uses it wrong, should it throw an exception (otherwise user might not notice what's wrong)?

And to Nathaniel Currier: the mothod is jQuery.trim() not jQuery.fn.trim() so it is not chained.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this was their design rationale, but using `call()` will work with objects that are not strings:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = String.prototype.trim.call(a); // same result as b = '1,2,3'
var c = a.trim(); // => generates TypeError
```

Notice that their polyfill coerces `text` to a string with `( text + "" )`.

Answer (score 2):

`text.trim()` will throw an error (`TypeError: .... has no method 'trim'`) when `text` is not a string, while `String.prototype.trim.call(text)` will not.

Comment: This answer is misleading. When `text` is null or undefined, `String.prototype.trim.call(text)` throws an exception. It will absolutely throw up.

Answer (score 1):

String.trim() is not available in all (older) browsers so they use native if available (as its faster) or their own implementation if not...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

also see this for information about how Function.prototype.call() behaves
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: OP isn't asking about the reason for a polyfill but about why they use `trim.call(text)` instead of `text.trim()` when `String.trim()` is available.

Comment: true, my guess is to avoid exceptions, and not break chaining